# How to get my node listed on Rinkeby testnet stats?

Tags: rinkeby

Hey all I'm running a full node for rinkeby testnet, but unfortunately I could neither find it on https://www.rinkeby.io/#stats nor https://ethernodes.org/network/4/nodes, I'm curious how to be eligible for listing on those pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `--ethstats` option in geth.
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Also this section on "Full Nodes" should be helpful, especially setting the `--ethstats` section as well as connecting to the correct bootnode.
https://www.rinkeby.io/#geth

In case you do not have synced yet, get the rinkeby.json file from the link above, then run:

`geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby init rinkeby.json`

Then run geth in some `--syncmode` e.g. `--syncmode=full` or `--syncmode=light` and substitute PUTYOUROWNNAMEHERE with a node name of your choice.

`geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --cache=1024 --syncmode=full --ethstats='PUTYOUROWNNAMEHERE:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io' --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303`

Comment: what will be in place of PUTYOUROWNNAMEHERE in ethstats='PUTYOUROWNNAMEHERE:Respect my authoritah!@stats.rinkeby.io'

Comment: You can choose any value of your own for PUTYOUROWNNAMEHERE. the second part, which is separated by the semicolon (:Respect my authoritah!) is the password which is needed by the stats server running on stats.rinkeby.io